# joining data points - added lines

Tags: plotting

I have a set of data {x,y,stdev}, and I want to have a SINGLE line joining the data points.

Whenever I put Joined -> True while running ListLogLogPlot, I get all these extraneous lines that I'm not able to deduce where they're originating from.

```
data3 = {{1.25`*^-7, 6.505`*^-7, 
    9.1`*^-9}, {1.2499999999999999`*^-6, 0.0000598392`, 
    8.32`*^-7}, {0.000012499999999999999`, 0.0021682996`, 
    0.0000290116`}, {0.000125`, 0.0264216604`, 
    0.0011165428`}, {0.00125`, 0.1169769169`, 
    0.0015663171`}, {0.012499999999999999`, 0.4577327298`, 
    0.0107049024`}, {0.125`, 1.8380050695499999`, 
    0.074451469`}, {1.25`, 5.796026990950001`, 0.4667664415`}, {12.5`,
     12.6452287892`, 2.9714758632`}, {125.`, 15.167773831949999`, 
    3.4492264127`}, {2.5`*^-7, 2.5947`*^-6, 
    3.6`*^-8}, {2.4999999999999998`*^-6, 0.0001998515`, 
    2.9297`*^-6}, {0.000024999999999999998`, 0.0051567977`, 
    0.0000906581`}, {0.00025`, 0.0426349414`, 
    0.0005633788`}, {0.0025`, 0.1721446492`, 
    0.0040464007`}, {0.024999999999999998`, 0.664622794`, 
    0.018272221`}, {0.25`, 2.66528408005`, 0.114312145`}, {2.5`, 
    7.78070269025`, 0.8960672623`}, {25.`, 14.321022694500002`, 
    3.6701272203`}, {250.`, 18.893069122900002`, 7.3919788655`}};

ListLogLogPlot[{data3[[;; , 1 ;; 2]]}, Joined -> True]
```

When I do this, I get a plot that looks like this
[image]

And not a single line connecting the data:
[image]

How do I resolve this issue? Logically I'm not able to see where the additional Joining is coming from that's creating the extra lines.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea is to use [`ListCurvePathPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot), especially if your curve doesn't conform to a function (i.e., there are multiple y-values for a single x-value), although you will have to work a bit to get the desired log scaling. First, here is [`ListCurvePathPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot) on your data:

```
ListCurvePathPlot[data3[[All, ;;2]]]
```

[image]

Next, here is how to modify things to get log scaling:

```
ListCurvePathPlot[
    Log[data3[[All, ;;2]]],
    AxesOrigin -> {Log[10^-7],Log[10^-7]},
    Ticks->{Charting`ScaledTicks["Log"],Charting`ScaledTicks["Log"]}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The data set is unsorted and this causes zigzags. Try this:

```
ListLogLogPlot[SortBy[data3[[;; , 1 ;; 2]], First], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This solved it - thank you so much!

Comment: Or just `ListLogLogPlot[Sort[data3[[;; , 1 ;; 2]]], Joined -> True]`

Comment: @wiscoYogi You're welcome.